# donet 6 SQLite.Interop.dll exception on macos m1 chip

Tags: c#, .net, apple-m1, system.data.sqlite

I got the below error when I try to open up an SQLiteConnection using System.Data.SQLite

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libSQLite.Interop.dll, 0x0001): tried: 'libSQLite.Interop.dll' (no such file),
 '/usr/local/lib/libSQLite.Interop.dll' 
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture 
(have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libSQLite.Interop.dll' (no such file)
```

Comment: https://sqlite.org/forum/info/c785cbb6d537914c7e078e7cb923238e5f517ea77b13177a59216f50ef88b2a7

Comment: so there is no workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  After some search on google, it seems that the implementaion on M1 is not yet done.

https://sqlite.org/forum/info/f985511fd94fb44cd77465195f88416631590cb3cee84003f9d8561c8e2a58fe

Comment: If linking to another source you should try to include some details about the linked information and/or title since links can break in the future and your link is otherwise useless.